# Running PM2 in Read-Only mode

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi

I currently have a Raspberry Pi 3B running a production CNC machine, using cncJS and it's great, however, to prevent data curruption due to unexpected shutdowns, which might happen a lot, I decided to install a script found on [Adafruit](https://learn.adafruit.com/read-only-raspberry-pi/) which essentially turns the SD card into RO-mode.

Problem is that cncJS runs with [PM2](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/) and wants to write logs and stuff on the home directory, which is RO and gives errors (log RW error), not starting the app.

If I set "PM2_HOME=/tmp/.pm2" (/etc/systemd/system/pm2-pi.service), it creates a new folder there, but doesn't find the dump file where the app configs are stored and fails to load anything.

Is there a way to run PM2 in Read-Only mode? I don't need logs, just the bare app running.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you simply tried copying everything needed there? You could even setup a RAM-disk and copy the program, configs, etc there.

Comment: @DocWeird If I set the home directory to /tmp, it creates folders there, but it doesn't find any config there, basically loading nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I was in your exact position, what I did was I preceded the `pm2` command with the path I wanted it to create the .pm2 directory on, as follows:

`PM2_HOME='/media/pen/.pm2' pm2 start`

Change `/media/pen/` to the path you want it to run on.

I created an alias in .bashrc so that it would fill in that prefix everytime I typed `pm2`:

`alias pm2="PM2_HOME='/media/pen/.pm2' pm2"`

You may need to specify your log outputs paths when starting pm2, I'm not sure.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).